# Setting the CRS of Raster in standalone PyGQIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, gdal, pyqgis-3, standalone

I'm generating raster files without a CRS and would like to assign one. I am attempting to use GDAL's assign projection, which works perfectly inside QGIS, but seems to have no effect when run in my standalone python environment. Any thoughts?

```py
    alg_params_DEM = {
    'ADVANCED_MODIFIERS': '',
    'CELLSIZE': 1,
    'CLASS': '2',
    'INPUT': las_loc,
    'MEDIAN': '',
    'MINIMUM': '',
    'SLOPE': '',
    'SMOOTH': '',
    'SPIKE': '',
    'VERSION64': True,
    'XYUNITS': 0,
    'ZUNITS': 0,
    'OUTPUT_DTM': home_folder+'\\DEM.dtm'
    }
    
    dem = processing.run('fusion:gridsurfacecreate', alg_params_DEM)

    processing.run("fusion:dtm2tif",
    {'INPUT':home_folder+'/DEM.dtm','MASK':False,'OUTPUT':home_folder+'/DEM.tif'})

    processing.run("gdal:assignprojection",  
    {'INPUT':home_folder+'/DEM.tif','CRS':'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:28355")'})
```